# Pylint super constructor doesn't trigger E1120

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

`Pylint` has an existing error `E1120` which will trigger when a value is missing from a constructor. This, however, doesn't trigger in inheritance. For example, look at this:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = Child()
    p = Parent()
```

As you can see, the `Parent` class constructor takes an argument `x` but the `Child`, which inherits from it, is not passing in anything.

If we run `pylint --errors-only X.py` just for the errors we get this one:

> X.py 13:8: E1120: No value for argument 'x' in constructor call (no-value-for-parameter)

This is for the direct call to `Parent()` at the end of the file. There is no error generated from the instantiation of `Child()` nor from call to `super().__init__()` which is an error. Specifically, running this directly with `python` results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X.py", line 12, in <module>
    c = Child()
  File "X.py", line 8, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Therefore I would expect `pylint` to catch this as an error. Am I missing something? Or is this an issue in `pylint`?

Relevant versions:
pylint 2.1.1
astroid 2.0.4
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)

Comment: Note that ``pylint`` is a static type checker. This means it has a hard time deriving *behaviour* of code. Since ``super`` requires tracing possibly complex inheritance, many static tools will not even try.

Comment: I see, thanks @MisterMiyagi. I was surprised that it wasn't something that `pylint` would catch but I understand that inheritance can get messy so if it is a known limitation then there isn't much to do about it.